# renaming files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have files in format:

```
schema_tableName_1.sql
schema_tableName_2.sql
schema_tableName_3.sql
...
```

How can I rename the files so that the format looks like this:

```
tableName_1.sql
tableName_2.sql
tableName_3.sql
...
```

The files should stay in the same directory. I tried:

```
mv "*schema_tableName*"  tableName_*
```

Comment: how about `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: How about [rename](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/rename.htm)? Another option would be to use zsh instead of bash and use the fine `zmv` command. As a last resort, you could loop over the files and `mv` each individual file. _bash_ itself does not have a bulk-rename command.

Comment: `for file in ./*.sql; do echo mv -v "$file" "${file#*_}"; done`

Comment: `rename schema_ '' schema_tableName_*.sql`

Comment: `mmv` may help: `mmv 'schema_tableName*' 'tableName*'`

Answer (score 1):

> I tried:
>
> ```
> mv "*schema_tableName*"  tableName_*
> ```

Nothing along those lines can possibly work.

In the first place, note that the quotation marks around `"*schema_tableName*"` suppress pathname expansion of their contents.  That is, they cause the asterisks (`*`) to be treated as ordinary characters. Generally speaking, it is the shell, not commands executed by it, that is responsible for interpreting patterns, so passing such filenames through to `mv` does nothing useful for you.

In the second place, if the various target files do not already exist then `tableName_*` will expand either to itself or to nothing, depending on the current values of the shell options, but neither of these is useful to you.

In the third place, suppose you actually had the command

```
mv schema_tableName_1.sql schema_tableName_2.sql schema_tableName_3.sql \
          tableName_1.sql        tableName_2.sql        tableName_3.sql
```

or

```
mv schema_tableName_1.sql tableName_1.sql \
   schema_tableName_2.sql tableName_2.sql \
   schema_tableName_3.sql tableName_3.sql
```

or something that would expand to one of those.  It seems like you're going for something like that, but `mv` doesn't do what you want with those.  It does not perform pairwise moves, other than when given only a single pair of non-option arguments.  When more than two non-option arguments are presented to it, the last must name a directory, and the files named by all the others are moved into that directory.<sup>*</sup>

To perform pairwise moves, you need a `mv` command for each pair.  A shell `for` loop seems natural for this.  And you need somehow to generate the destination filename from the source filename.  The shell has transformative parameter expansion options that are well suited to this.  Overall:

```
for f in schema_tableName_*.sql; do
  mv "${f}" "${f#schema_}"
done
```

That expands the glob `schema_tableName_*.sql` and for each resulting filename in turn, sets shell variable `f` to the filename and executes the commands between `do` and `done`.  The `"${f#schema_}"` expands to the value of variable `f` with the prefix "schema_" removed, if present.  That gives you exactly the pairwise `mv` commands you want.

Additionally, since you tagged Linux, you consider using the `rename` command.  This performs potentially many file renamings based on string substitution, so it can afford a slightly simpler command, but it is specific to Linux:

```
rename schema_ '' schema_tableName_*.sql
```

I generally recommend preferring standard commands such as `mv` over platform-specific ones such as `rename`, as that develops skills that are more broadly reusable (to MacOS, for example), but YMMV.

---

<sup>*</sup>Or you can specify a target directory via the `-t` option, but the destination must in any case be a directory.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `rename` for batch renaming linux command ?

Or you can create a bash script that loop for a giver pattern and replace to another something like:

```
orig=schema_tableName_
dest=tableName_

for(i=0; i<(ls ${orig}*|wc -l); i++) {
  cp ${orig} ${dest} -v
}
```

there are other options: https://www.makeuseof.com/batch-rename-files-in-linux/

Comment: `rename` is a good suggestion but your loop is not functional code. Try: `for f in schema_tableName_* ; do mv "${f}" "${f#schema_}" ; done`